# Class references to local module function

Tags: javascript, node.js, module

Say, there is a module that exports a class. Does it violates any principles to reference declared locally functions from class method?

An example:

```
function doSomething() {}

class Cat {
    constructor () {}
    say () {
        doSomething()
        return 'meow'
    }
}

module.exports.Cat = Cat
```

Comment: I write Node modules like this all the time. Aside from personal style, this gives you the ability to clearly separate private methods from the public API of your module.

Answer (score 2):

Not only does this not violate any principles, it's a good way to organize behavior. `doSomething()` will be a function that is private to the module. This makes it easy to expose a consistent interface to your class without worrying about implementation.

So for example in `mod.js`:

```
function doSomething() {
    console.log("I'm doing something")
}

class Cat {
    constructor () {}
    say () {
        doSomething()
    }
}

module.exports.Cat = Cat
```

Now use it:

```
var mod = require('./mod')
var cat = new mod.Cat
cat.say()
// logs to console: "I'm doing something"
```